# Audio issue after my laptop goes to sleep or lock it

Tags: 20.04, sound, headphones, audio-jack

I am using ubuntu 20.04, I always use headphones but whenever my laptop goes to sleep or if I lock the screen for a few seconds, then after reopening my laptop sound does not work like before seems like as if my headphones are partially plugged in, I hear distorted and very low sound. But after unplug and plug works for me. And yes after unplug and plug it always asks me to select the device.

[image]